# Why does Unity let you install iOS Build Support on Windows?

Tags: unity, ios, build-process

When installing Unity on a Windows machine, you are allowed to select "iOS Build Support" as one of the components to install. However, it is not possible to make an iOS build from Windows. Why is this package available on Windows? What does it offer?

Comment: You'll still need a Mac available on the network, but:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as i know when you build for IOS on windows it will generate an Xcode project that you then need to build on mac.

As you can't make IOS bundles on windows the only thing you can do is to make the process better by not having the requirement of installing Unity on both windows and OSX. You could set up automated tools which take the output from unity and automatically build the game on a mac so that you don't have to go though as many hoops. See [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Note for anyone else who decides to try this out: Using iOS build support to generate the xcode project on an extremely powerful Windows, machine and then transferring it to a Mac Mini to compile, is several orders of magnitude slower than pulling code changes to the Mac Mini and generating the xcode project there. For my purposes, iOS build support on Windows is less than useless. Maybe if you have a standalone file server, this would be practical to use.

Comment: I don't mean that a Mac Mini is faster than a Windows machine - in my experience, a Mac Mini is significantly slower than a Windows machine with comparable hardware. However, Unity's iOS build support on Windows is extremely slow, and the time to transfer a multi-gigabyte xcode project to the Mac far outweighs any potential time savings you might theoretically get from building it on Windows.

Comment: @user45623 Several orders of magnitude? Like, days instead of milliseconds?

Comment: @user253751 "Orders of magnitude" are usually understood to mean powers of 10. So if we took the loosest definition of "several", that would mean "100x longer" (which could be 1 minute vs 2 hours). This was almost 4 years ago so I don't remember the exact numbers, but I think it was something like 5 - 10 minutes to compile the Xcode project on my Mac Mini, vs. 1 hour to compile the Xcode project on a PC and another hour to transfer it to the Mac so I could actually compile an IPA. So I was probably exaggerating, but the point was it wasn't even worth compiling the Xcode project on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Developing on Windows and building on Mac is the major reason for its existance on Windows!
Lots of programmers does not like to code on Mac. And `iOS build support on Windows` make modifying iOS buildsettings on Windows be possible!